# take in and return ordinary text with gpg in the terminal

Tags: encryption, gpg

I made a text file:

```
$ cat sheep.txt

mary had a little lamb
```

..then encrypted it in the terminal:

`gpg --encrypt --recipient 49673952 sheep.txt`

Now there are two sheep files:

```
$ ls -la sheep.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 cardamom cardamom  25 Jun 15 22:02 sheep.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 cardamom cardamom 622 Jun 15 22:02 sheep.txt.gpg
```

If you put the second one onto the screen, you can see it is more a binary file than a text file:

```
$ cat sheep.txt.gpg

���/�0��JT�H�ߗ�V<��n�2��,on�:] *�{��RU=�j)�8R�8��-؛��)�j�����}��E�X+-c�q龵��!1�qwm"��H�ｦc�Վ;
```

I would like it to be more like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

Pef4eu2VSVhhCaGUqvWSdRihyaIbSf8ztJ64e11rzKcgvM+zNAIQYy5ZLoZkGXzG
EExxTuCn0t51DJkEesbb0UVgT0NyWVY9+c2GVIrQMpsET785+dHO2KWTGaAivEfk

-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

How do you get gpg to give you that kind of output? Actually, would prefer it dumped on the screen than saved in a file.

Second thing which would be handy is how to perhaps put the plaintext into the command rather than into a file,

```
gpg --encrypt --recipient 49673952 'mary had a little lamb'
```

..doesn't work. Actually it's a bit of a security risk to do that, is important to delete the plaintext files after and here would be important to have a space at the start so it does not go into your history. Would be handy some times to be able to do that not sure if I always will due to the risk, but the main question I am asking is how to get gpg to give you that other kind of output, if possible on the terminal rather than in a file.

*Update:*

Am thinking it's related to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306865/what-are-the-standard-encryption-file-formats

..and may not be possible with just gpg, but the output of gpg may need to be piped into something.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked it out:

```
gpg --output - --encrypt --armor --recipient 49673952 <(echo "$mary had a little lamb")
```

`--output -` dumps it to STDOUT as per the [docs](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Input-and-Output.html) and does not write any file to disk.

Then the last bit avoids reading from a file, although as mentioned that is a security risk if it goes into the history